# How should I refresh gui that is displaying data from a mySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am using JDBC to connect to a mySQL database in my program. During runtime, the user can modify the contents of the database by adding new ones (more functionality is coming but right now that's all I have). However, when a new entry into the database is created I want the gui that is displaying the content to update themselves with the modified data.

I know how to update the gui elements, but that doesn't seem to apply to the ResultSet created from my database.

I am quite new to mySQL and JDBC so any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: you cannot push update from mysql, however you can poll the DB tables for any data update and act accordingly. polling can be based on time based trigger(not DB triggers)

Comment: In my program, the user clicks a button to confirm the addition of an entry, so I don't really need to monitor changes directly from the database because I will always know when they take place. Could   you elaborate the "act accordingly" part of your answer ?

Comment: since the triggering event is known to you, after adding you can make a select all call to db, and you will have the updated dataset. another approach could be caching the data (you will need thord party support for that)

Comment: So you're saying I should close the window and rebuild the gui with the updated dataset ? I was trying to avoid needing to restart the program every time something is added, but if it's the only option then I will use that

Comment: no, i am saying if a user is clicking a button say "ADD" so after you added the new record and if it has been successfully added then fetch all records. Like i said it has some performance cost, you can go for caching or any ORM framework like Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First questions:
 - If it is a web application, you can use Ajax and ajax callback to manage return of your application (success or failure)
 - If it is a standard application, you can manage in that way (which work from my side):
   As soon as user added data, you needs to wait the result of your database. If (insert/update/delete) does not return any exception, you have to modify your GUI (add/update/remove) your display. If you have any issue you should not modify your gui.

Do not perform any select all, as you can crash your application in case of huge db.